# how can I include the label of a text field on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-apps-script

I have a form that dynamically creates a text field and label for the text field.   When I use this.form to get the information submitted, I only get the text field which means very little without the label that goes with it.

Below is an abridged version of the text which I hope is enough.  I am using jQuery if that helps.

dynamically created form:
/

```
/dynamically created based on choice options from a form
<input type="text" id="cV_'+curChoice+'" class="numeric" size="1" value="1"> <label for="cV_'+curChoice+'">'+curChoice+'</label><br><hr>'

<input class='action' id='saveButton' type='button' value='SAVE' onclick='saveChoices()' />

<script>
function saveChoices(){
var choiceNum = this.form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution.  I had to add a name to the field.

```
$('#choices').append('<input type="text" name="'+curChoice+'" class="numeric" size="1" value="1">'+curChoice+'<br><hr>');
```